# How to use recursive types

Tags: ocaml

I need a function that sums up all numbers in a tree, recursively.

So I defined:

1. A tree type, which I have defined as
   `type tree = [] | Intlist of int list | Treelist of tree list;;`
2. A sum function, like

```
let rec sum_list list = 
  match list with  
    Treelist (head::tail) -> (sum_list head) + (sum_list tail) 
  | Intlist (head::tail)  -> head + (sum_list tail) 
  | []                    -> 0
```

> The error I get on trying to compile this is this:
>
> Error: This expression has type tree list but an expression was expected of type tree

which refers to thesecond sumlist in the Treelist clause.
For me it seems that an expression of type tree list should of type tree.

What is wrong? The function or my definition of a tree?

Comment: A minor style note: function application has a higher precedence than `+`, so you can write `sum_list head + sum_list tail` rather than `(sum_list head) + (sum_list tail)`. Both are valid, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it is better to not use the `[]` constructor in type definition when learning OCaml. Using this `[]` constructor is only useful when defining alternative list types (with GADTs for instance), and by doing so it shadows the usual `[]` constructor from the usual list type.

Let's thus replace it with `Empty` in the definition of tree:

```
type tree =
| Empty
| Intlist of int list 
| Treelist of tree list
```

Second, it sounds like you might be misreading the definition of `TreeList` in

```ml
type tree =
| Empty
| Intlist of int list 
| Treelist of tree list
```

This definition does not mean that a tree of list is a tree. It means that one can build a tree by applying the constructor `TreeList` on a tree of list:

```ml
let treelist (x:tree list): tree = TreeList x
```

Thus in

```
let rec sum_list list = match list with
  | Treelist (head::tail) -> sum_list head + sum_list tail
  | Intlist (head :: tail) -> head + sum_list tail
  | Empty -> 0
```

the typechecker is correctly complaining that `tail` is not a tree but a list of trees. The tree that contains the list of trees `tail` would be `TreeList tail`. The same is true for the `IntList` case, `tail` is not a tree but a list of integers, and the tree that would contain the list of integers `tail` would be `IntList tail`.

Comment: Note also that the last example features non-exhaustive pattern matching, as the `Treelist` and `Intlist` constructors may both take an _empty_ list.

Answer (score 6):

Look at this expression:

```
(sum_list head) + (sum_list tail)
```

The type of the head is `tree`, but the type of the tail is `tree list`.  So they can't both be a proper argument for the `sum_list` function. That's what the compiler is telling you.

Later in your code you also apply `sum_list` to a list of ints.

OCaml is a strongly typed language. You can't have a function that accepts an argument of different types (`tree`, `tree list`, `int list`). You most likely need three different functions, one for each type.

Your definition of `tree` is OK (though it's risky to redefine `[]` since you might need it elsewhere in your code with its usual type).